# When using Facebook login, how do I skip the permissions page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need only the basic permissions "email", "public_profile","user_friends" and I need all of them for my app to work.

FB login takes the user to permissions page and he/she can just uncheck email and user_friends and I will have to handle it separately.

Yes, I do understand the trust equation here that has been discussed in a lot of questions on SO.But a lot of apps somehow circumvent this. e.g. Uber

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? what does uber circumvent? why do you want to skip the permissions page?

Comment: @luschn: please see the screenshot. Uber get all the three permissions without the "Edit Permissions" button underneath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uber is probably using an old App created before end of April 2014. Those basic permissions where included back then. In newer Apps you can´t force a user to authorize all permissions, he will always be able to skip the extended ones.

One good way is to use the "return_scopes" flag of FB.login and check if the user accepted the neccessary permissions right after the authorized your App: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.2